# Is there a way for SystemChrome SystemUIMode to always show top status bar but have immersiveSticky bottom?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, statusbar, navigationbar

Using Flutter 2.5.2, testing on Pixel 2 and Iphone SE (2020),

So for my app I want to maximize screen space but keep the top status bar throughout most of the app. I would like to hide the bottom system navigation, but it seems that using
 `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);` causes the bottom system overlay to go into the leanBack mode or something.

Since I have scrolling features with my own bottom navigation bar, it seems that I can't scroll without having to tap the screen to show the system overlay on 'manual' mode. Then the app gestures without the system bottom navigation, blocking my bottom navigation bar. 'immersiveSticky' would work, but I would like the top status bar almost always shown. Using `SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky` seems to ignore the ```overlays:[]``.

Does any one know how to use `SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback` for my gestures to go through or have `SystemUiOverlay.top` always on with the bottom as `immersiveSticky` with something like:
`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);`?

Or could there be a workaround where I can get a 'copy' of the top status bar and create my own widget that i can use as a top status bar and keep `SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky`?

[Reference for SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIMode.html)

Answer (score 0):

By adding `SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback` will actually solve your problem.

First, set your app only show status bar and hiden navigation bar using:

```
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

Then add callback to listen for changes of UI Mode and when a change is detected, you reset UI mode

```
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIChangeCallback((systemOverlaysAreVisible) async {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
        });
      });
```

The code obove will hide the navigation bar agian when it reapprears.